# Reconnecting a rewound 110vac motor to power

Tags: ac-motor

[image]Motor is (about) 5hp 110vac and powers a a table saw.
Motor was recently rewound but previous owner did not reconnect to the power cord.
There are no info plates on the motor to help w/ reconnecting.
There are 4 wires coming out of the motor in two pairs. One pair is 1 black wire and 1 white wire, the other pair is 1 black wire and 1 green wire.
The wires on the power side of the connection are a typical black, white, and green which go to the power via the on/ off switch on the front of the machine.
So I need to know which wires on the motor (right in photo) connect to which wires from the switched power wires (left in photo)

Motor wires: (on right in photo)
black, white, black, green.

Power wires from switch:
(On left in photo)
black, white, green.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you look the the inside of the box cover?

Comment: Is there a big capacitor bolted to the motor?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Nothing on inside of cover plate, an no starting capacitor. Was hoping I could use a multimeter and check for continuity to figure out where to connect power, but being a nooby I don’t have that level of knowledge yet.

Comment: After doing more research, my "educated" guess would be as follows: 1. The two black wires from the motor one black goes to the starting windings, and the other black goes to the main windings. 2.The white wire from the motor is the return wire. And 3. The green wire from the motor is the ground. So to connect to power: A) the two black wires from the motor should connect to the black wire from the power. B) The white wire from the motor should connect to the white wire from the power. C) the green wire should connect to a good ground.